# mathematical formula to compute sum of all sub sequences of a number N

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, algorithms, contest-math

We have a number say N and we list down all its sub- sequences and sum them up.SAY for n=123 ,the sum is 177(123+12+23+13+1+2+3). I came across this mathematical formula which computes the sum taking number N as string S.Here is the method described but i could not understand the logic used.

```
                  ANSWER = 0
                  for i in range(0,size(S))
                  weight of 2 -> 2^i
                  weight of 11 -> 11^(size(S)-i-1)
                  total weight at S[i] -> s[i]*(weight of 2)*(weight of 11)   
                 ANSWER = (ANSWER + weight at s[i]) 
                 RETURN ANS
```

If THEY TAKE N AS string s "abcd",THEY WRITE ALL ITS SUB SEQUENCES
 $$``‘‘a",‘‘b",‘‘c",‘‘d"‘$$
$$``‘‘ab",‘‘ac",‘‘ad",‘‘bc",‘‘bd",‘‘cd"$$
$$``‘‘abc",‘‘abd",‘‘bcd",‘‘acd"`$$
$$``‘‘abcd"`$$

AND USE THIS FORMULA

## $sum_{i=0}^{modS-1}=Si*weighted sum of its positions$

=           $$a∗(1∗10^0+3∗10^1+3∗10^2+1∗10^3)+b∗(1∗10^0+4∗10^1+2∗10^2)+c∗(4∗10^0+4∗10^1)+d∗(8)  is eq1$$

=
                                                       $$a∗((2^0)∗(11^3))+b∗((2^1)∗(11^2))+c∗((2^2)∗(11^1))+d∗((2^3)∗(11^0)  is eq2$$
HOW do we get this pattern while solving it ?Can anyone explain how we got equation 1 and 2?

Comment: What is "M" in the code?

Comment: @martycohen since the result can be very large so we do mod using a big number 1000000000+7 but please ignore this part as mod M IS not the crux part ?can you just explain how we got equation 2 from equation 1 ?

Comment: Allow me to draw your attention to [our policy on contest problems](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774). What's the source of this problem?